# React js pagination - deleting null values from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make pagination logic that would change page numbers when you click on the last index.

E.G

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

If user clicks on 5, it should change to

```
2 3 4 5 6
```

and so on ...

I managed to so, however I'm assigning first element to null, therefore my array is getting bigger, since I'm not deleting any element.

I want to delete all null values in the array, and I tried to use various methods with underscore: `_wihout, _reject`, but it always gives me an error that `_ is undefined`.

This is the snippet of that particular code

```
 handleClick(event) {
        this.setState({
            currentPage: Number(event.target.id),
        })
        if (this.state.currentPage === this.state.pageNumbers[this.state.pageNumbers.length-1]) {
             this.state.pageNumbers.push(this.state.pageNumbers.length + 1);
             this.state.pageNumbers[this.state.startIndex] = null;
             this.state.startIndex++;
             this.state.pageNumbers._.without(array, null);
               // delete null values
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the `setState` method is asynchronous. You have to keep that in mind and use the second parameter in `setState(state, callback)` to get the new state values. e.g.

```
this.setState({
    currentPage: Number(event.target.id),
}, () => {
    if (this.state.currentPage === this.state.pageNumbers[this.state.pageNumbers.length - 1]) {}
    // and so on
})
```

To filter `null` values out you don't need to use a third party library. You can use `Array#filter` to achieve it. Besides that you should not directly set the state fields with `this.state.xy = yz`.

To manipulate state variables it's always a great idea to make a new copy of it and assign it later with `setState`. Something along this:

```
const pageNumbers = Object.assign({}, this.state.pageNumbers); // copy
pageNumbers[this.state.startIndex] = null;
this.setState({
    pageNumbers: pageNumbers.filter(noNull => noNull),
    startIndex: this.state.startIndex + 1
});
```